# Linux - command to list files (except ls)

Tags: shell, command-line, ls

> Imagine you were working on a system
>   and someone accidentally deleted the
>   `ls` command (`/bin/ls`). How could
>   you get a list of the files in the
>   current directory? Try it.

I tried many methods and also searched on the Internet but nothing. I want to ask beside `ls` command what command can we use to list out all the files.

Answer (score 36):

```
echo *
```

... will show files in the current folder through file globbing on Bourne compatible shells.

This lists all files down one level:

```
echo */*
```

In Bash, if globstar is set (set with `shopt -s globstar`, unset with `shopt -u globstar`), this will list all files recursively:

```
echo **
```

Comment: Beyond the homework exercise, `echo *` is useful in practice, when you've screwed up your system so that you can't execute *any* program (e.g. you removed `libc.so` or `ld.so`), but you still have a running shell.

Comment: In bash4 (I think) and zsh, you can use `echo **/*` to do this recursively, too.

Comment: @Reid: gonna test that. Nice find.

Comment: Good one, @Gilles.  Learned that from old DEC systems which could not have access to either /usr or /bin in certain boot conditions and boot scripts needed to make 'cat' and 'ls' functions themselves.

Comment: nice, I first learned about echo * from http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/hack/recovery.html

Comment: I suppose this is also marginally faster, since it avoids the invocation of the `ls` executable.

Comment: @Gilles, exactly what happened to me once. Quite a ride ;-)

Comment: @Reid that depends on the state of globstar. Set with `shopt -s globstar`. But `*/*` does work to list all files down one level in any case.

Answer (score 23):

```
find -maxdepth 1 
find -maxdepth 1 -ls
```

less  <kbd>TAB TAB</kbd>

finds -ls switch is independent of /bin/ls and has its own format, and displays detail information:

```
127432    0 drwxr-xr-x   2 stefan   stefan         48 Apr  8 22:51 ./temp/falsch/.hiddenfalsch
127447    0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 stefan   stefan          9 Apr  8 22:51 ./temp/falsch/linkfalsch -> subfalsch
127427    0 drwxr-xr-x   2 stefan   stefan         48 Apr  8 22:51 ./temp/.hiddenmusik
```

another, details showing possibility, is `stat`

```
stat *
  File: `halx0o'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 807h/2055d  Inode: 102701      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/  stefan)   Gid: ( 1000/  stefan)
Access: 2011-04-08 22:38:18.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2009-07-23 03:16:15.000000000 +0200
Change: 2011-04-09 23:29:13.000000000 +0200
  File: `ho ho ho'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 807h/2055d  Inode: 115835      Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/  stefan)   Gid: ( 1000/  stefan)
Access: 2011-04-08 22:38:18.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2010-07-24 14:12:48.000000000 +0200
Change: 2011-04-09 23:29:13.000000000 +0200
```

Answer (score 11):

To make it look like `ls`, I'd use Bash's `for` loop:

```
for i in *; do echo $i; done
```

If that doesn't work, I'd try Python `;)` :

```
python -c "import glob; print '\n'.join(glob.glob('/home/*'))"
```

Comment: `import glob; print '\n'.join(glob.glob('/home/*'))` would work just as well.

Answer (score 6):

```
find .
```

Though you probably would want to enter whatever limiting parameters you need.

Answer (score 6):

Good ol' vim ;) (with sorting, browsing, etc)

```
vim .
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the `echo` version, but this prints out one entry per line for greater readability:

```
printf %s\\n ./*
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' ./*
```

Recursively (for bash 4+; other shells either need a different option to set it or have globstar enabled by default):

```
shopt -s globstar
printf %s\\n ./**/*
```

Comment: No need for the '/*', a simple `**` will recurse into all directories if `globstar` is set. Just change to `printf '%s' **`.

Answer (score 3):

`lsattr ./*`

`getfacl ./*` will display permissions too

`grep -l '.*' ./*`

`awk 'FNR==1 {print FILENAME}' ./*` works with GNU awk

`debugfs /dev/sdX` replace sdX with whatever partition you want to do an ls on, then you can ls inside debugfs

```
debugfs:  cd /
debugfs:  ls -l
      2   40755 (2)      0      0    4096  6-Apr-2011 01:01 .
      2   40755 (2)      0      0    4096  6-Apr-2011 01:01 ..
     11   40700 (2)      0      0   16384  5-Jul-2010 09:59 lost+found
 2392065   40755 (2)      0      0    4096  5-Jul-2010 09:59 boot
 2228225   40755 (2)      0      0    4096  5-Jul-2010 09:59 sys
 1376257   40755 (2)      0      0    4096  5-Jul-2010 09:59 proc
 4915201   40755 (2)      0      0    4096  5-Jul-2010 09:59 dev
 3473409   40755 (2)      0      0   12288 10-Apr-2011 22:05 etc
  98305  100644 (1)      0      0       0  6-Jul-2010 12:05 .autofsck
 3342337   40755 (2)      0      0    4096  5-Apr-2011 15:05 var
 3932161   41777 (2)      0      0    4096 10-Apr-2011 22:11 tmp
  ..........
debugfs:
```

`lynx ./`

`mc` assuming you have midnight commander installed

Answer (score 2):

How about `dir` command? :)

`/bin/dir`

Answer (score 1):

Well if I couldn't use ls within shell mode of emacs, I might switch to eshell mode or just a dired.

Answer (score 1):

If I have bash shell started (or any other shell with completion), I would probably just type '*' then tab.

Or as I usually have X started, I may also just do 'nautilus .', but OK that's for humans.

I may also try /usr/bin/lsattr

But in the real world what I would **really** do if such thing occured to me would certainly be:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash, or a shell with similar tab-completion, you don't need to use a real command at all: `wibble` followed by two tabs will get you a list of files in the current directory, and `wibble /bin/` followed by two tabs will show you what's left of /bin.  I once found myself in this situation (actually, I'd killed /bin entirely along with some other things), and started off using the `echo *` approach @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED suggested, but eventually found tab completion more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Another way with `tree`, not mentioned anywhere here, it goes recursively and unlike find or ls you don't have any errors (like: `Permission denied`, `Not a directory`) you also get the absolute path in case you want to feed the files to `xargs` or other command

```
tree -fai /pathYouWantToList >listOfFiles.list
```

the options meaning:

```
-a     All  files  are  printed.  By default tree does not print hidden files (those beginning with a dot
       `.').  In no event does tree print the file system constructs `.'  (current  directory)  and  `..'
       (previous directory).

-i     Makes tree not print the indentation lines, useful when used in conjunction with the -f option.

-f     Prints the full path prefix for each file.
```